# how to Change label NEW to QUALITY in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

Under Specail, you can see products with label " New" , "sale" , "best".

How to change the name from "sale" to "quality".

I need to the change in frontend of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Magento's translation functionality for this purpose: http://tomrobertshaw.net/2010/03/magento-themes-using-locales-with-translate-csv/